# Distinct Event based on how it was created

Tags: domain-driven-design, event-sourcing

I'm doing DDD analysis using event-storming, and run into this question:

Can we or should we define distinct events (e.g.: RouteCreatedByUser and RouteCreatedFromImport) based on how it was created?

Will "it depends" be the answer again? (e.g.: depends, if the way it was created will affect subsequent process / how the aggregate will be treated).

Or will the answer be flat out "no", just make one event (RouteCreated)?

Comment: There is defenitely no "no" answer. And you are right "it depends" on the context. It can also be just a matter of personal preferences. Sometimes it's more pragmatic to distinguish by type and sometimes by property.

Comment: If your subscription mechanism doesn't support hierarchical subscriptions then you may consider a single `RouteCreated` event, given it would be hard to catch all creation events otherwise as they would need to all be listed. Another thing to consider is if events all carry different properties. If they do and you have a single event then you may have many Optional or you would need to have different types of `CreationDetails`, which mean you would nest value objects into your events, where a flattened structure is usually better.

Comment: "It depends."  :)  Personally, unless the processing (read: how your aggregate applies the event) for the two cases is wildly different, I would just use one event type with a property saying how it came about.  It will also be a lot less work later if you add new "sources" later on.

Answer (score 0):

> You should always consider if your events have distinict business
>   significance. If they do, they should be separate. This allows them to
>   evolve independently.

Also, see how many things are common and how much is different. If you find some things which are different but not really generalisable, you should split the events. No use in having unused fields with lots of conditions when something is applicable and when it isn't.

If you fail to catch this distinction you would end up with low cohesion, lots of unused fields etc. Remember, that even sourcing is primarily about having an immutable event log. What it means is while you can modify the events if you need to do some simple schema migrations (in general, you shouldn't but sometimes it just makes more sense), you can never put any events in between or delete events.